# Updated SQL query returns no data, even with cross joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have been replacing all the old queries in my application, to remove the `*=` operator. In one of these queries, I am having a bit of trouble figuring out why my output is different.

This was the old query:

```
 SELECT 
    URMS_User_Name AS FE_Name,
    URMS_User_ID AS FE_Code, 
    COUNT( MRFS_FE_Code ) AS No_Of_Jobs, 
    SCRM_Service_Center_Name AS Service_Center_Name, 
    CSMSDVLP.fnGetExpertise( URMS_User_ID ) AS Expertise 
 FROM 
    TBL_User_Master, 
    TBL_Service_Center_Master, 
    TBL_User_Role, 
    TBL_MR_FE_Schedule 
 WHERE                
    USRL_Role_Code = 'FE' AND
    URMS_User_ID = USRL_User_ID AND      
    SCRM_Service_Center_ID = URMS_Service_Center_ID AND
    URMS_User_ID *= MRFS_FE_Code AND
    MRFS_Scheduled_Date >= '28-Oct-2014 00:00:00' AND 
    MRFS_Scheduled_Date <= '04-Nov-2014 00:00:00' 
 GROUP BY 
    SCRM_Service_Center_Name,
    URMS_User_Name,
    URMS_User_ID 
 ORDER BY 
    URMS_User_ID
```

And this is the updated query:

```
SELECT 
    URMS_User_Name AS FE_Name,
    URMS_User_ID AS FE_Code,
    COUNT( MRFS_FE_Code ) AS No_Of_Jobs,
    SCRM_Service_Center_Name AS Service_Center_Name, 
    CSMSDVLP.fnGetExpertise( URMS_User_ID ) AS Expertise 
FROM 
    TBL_User_Master 
    Left Join TBL_MR_FE_Schedule 
       ON URMS_User_ID = MRFS_FE_Code 
    Inner Join TBL_Service_Center_Master 
       ON SCRM_Service_Center_ID = URMS_Service_Center_ID 
    Inner Join TBL_User_Role 
       ON URMS_User_ID = USRL_User_ID 
WHERE 
    USRL_Role_Code = 'FE'
    AND MRFS_Scheduled_Date >= '28-Oct-2014 00:00:00' 
    AND MRFS_Scheduled_Date <= '04-Nov-2014 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    SCRM_Service_Center_Name,
    URMS_User_Name, 
    URMS_User_ID 
ORDER BY 
    URMS_User_ID
```

The old query returns data perfectly fine, but the new query returns empty rows. I tried replacing all joins with cross joins and same problem.

Although, weird thing is if I run the query without date condition, everything seems to work fine. So, now, I am confused whether I made a mistake or it is just the old operator acting crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on outer-joined tables belong in the ON clause. Outer-joined records have an MRFS_Scheduled_Date of NULL, so with your WHERE clause you remove these, thus turning your outer join into an inner join. As the WHERE clause is more restrictive than before, this may be the reason for not getting any result.

```
SELECT 
  URMS_User_Name AS FE_Name, 
  URMS_User_ID AS FE_Code, 
  COUNT( MRFS_FE_Code ) AS No_Of_Jobs, 
  SCRM_Service_Center_Name AS Service_Center_Name, 
  CSMSDVLP.fnGetExpertise( URMS_User_ID ) AS Expertise 
FROM TBL_User_Master 
LEFT JOIN TBL_MR_FE_Schedule ON URMS_User_ID = MRFS_FE_Code AND MRFS_Scheduled_Date >= '28-Oct-2014 00:00:00' AND MRFS_Scheduled_Date <= '04-Nov-2014 00:00:00' 
INNER JOIN TBL_Service_Center_Master ON SCRM_Service_Center_ID = URMS_Service_Center_ID 
INNER JOIN TBL_User_Role ON URMS_User_ID = USRL_User_ID 
WHERE USRL_Role_Code = 'FE'  
GROUP BY SCRM_Service_Center_Name, URMS_User_Name, URMS_User_ID 
ORDER BY URMS_User_ID;
```

Comment: So, I should move the date condition to the Join clause? Ok, let me try that quickly, and get back to you.

And it works. I had no idea, my outer joins were getting converted to inner joins automatically.